# Conditional Formatting of a value based on Yes or NO

Tags: excel, colors, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I have two ROWS, one has values and the other `Yes` or `NO`. I want the values in ROW 1 to be colored according to whether `Yes` or `NO` in ROW 2 in the corresponding column. For example:

```
   ROW 1  XXXX|XXXX|XXX|XXXX  
   ROW 2  YES | NO |YES| NO
```

There are no conditions to why ROW 1 should be yes or no, it's just the way it is.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

In conditional formatting, use this option:

[image]

And write this formula:

```
=If(B2="Yes",1,0)
```

And assuming your data is like this:

[image]

So, the highlight in Row1 changes depending on the value in Row2.
Hope this helps.
**Note:**
Remember, you only apply the formatting in `A2` then just copy and paste format to other cells.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Conditional Formatting tag wiki summary mentions Excel I take it that is the relevant software. Since OP mentions “the condition of Yes or NO” I take it formatting is required for both possibilities. I take it that the leftmost `XXXX` is in A1.

The simplest way may be to select Row1, which should automatically set the appropriate *Applies to* range, and apply a Conditional Formatting formula rule (required since the cell to be formatted is not the trigger for the formatting) of:

```
=A1="YES"
```

and formatting of choice (green highlight would be conventional).

The “NO” condition might be handled by simply formatting all of Row1 with ‘standard’ format, again being convention this might be red fill. The CF rule would then just override this where Row2 does not contain “NO”.

However another possibility is that there may be some cells in Row2 that contain neither “Yes” nor “NO” and where that is so the cell immediately above should not be conditionally formatted. In that case just add another formula rule similar to the one above:

```
=A1="NO"
```

but a different format (red fill).

Because the formatting is *conditional* there is no need for an IF construct, the formatting will only be triggered when the formula returns `TRUE`.